# Let user specify main tag for a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I observed that a web page title for questions asked here is generated by the first tag + full question. However the ordering for the tags is fixed once added, unless one removes all tag and re-add them one by one, it stays as-is.

Some tags in the middle of the list might not be a very good categorisation of the question, yet they get displayed in the web page title (title attribute of an HTML page) when a user removes the first tag. So is it OK to add a feature to reorder the list of tags, or to let the user specify which tag is the main one?

Comment: Isn't it always the tag most used on the site?

Comment: Daniel: Hmm yeah, I think so, but the most used tag might not be the most relevant to the question. One may add a tag just because it is somewhat related to a question, and that tag turns out to be the most used tag, which makes the title look funny as the tag and question doesn't have an apparent relationship.

Comment: Why put a somewhat related tag, and not just wholly related tags? Too many tags is also a problem